# Strange behavoir with find and du

Tags: bash, find, du

I'm trying to generate user usage in certain folders in a shell script and I'm finding some strange behavior with my find and du combination.

I have a folder with ~9500 files for a total of 5GB. 4GB of this folder is made up of 7 large files and the remaining 1GB is made up of small files (nearly 9000 of them). The issue I'm having is that my script seems to ignore a large portion of the files so the total usage reported by du is incorrect.

The line below gives the correct number for the total number of files (+1 for the total):

```
$ find . -type -f -exec du -ch {} + | wc -l
9596
```

However if I just try to get the total of all the files it returns and incorrect value.

```
$ find . -type -f -exec du -ch {} + 
...lines of files
139M total < this value is incorrect, should be ~5GB
```

If I limit the size to the large files (more than 25MB) it does pick up the large files and get closer but obviously is missing that many small files that make up the remaining 1GB.

```
$ find . -type -f -size +25M -exec du -ch {} + 
561M    ./largefile0
483M    ./largefile1
514M    ./largefile2
948M    ./largefile3
360M    ./largefile4
768M    ./largefile5
764M    ./largefile6
4.3G    total < this is the correct total for these files
```

Lastly, even stranger is if I run the command again without the size parameter and then grep for `large` it picks up the `largefile[0-6]` files.

```
$ find . -type -f -size +25M -exec du -ch {} + | grep large
561M    ./largefile0
483M    ./largefile1
514M    ./largefile2
948M    ./largefile3
360M    ./largefile4
768M    ./largefile5
764M    ./largefile6
```

So I'm not quite sure what is occurring here, it's as if there is a limit to the number of files du can report is its total but it always seem to equal 139M for this data-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking. If it's just an explanation of the result, then:

the `-exec {} +` predicate doesn't execute just once, it has a size limit, when that's reached the command is executed and a new "command" starts to be composed see: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/exec.c#n153

On my machine that size is ~128K.

```
$ find ./ -type f -name 'file*' -exec echo {} + 2>/dev/null | head -1 | wc -c
131056
```

For an example directory with about 40000 files, the command gets executed 7 times.

```
$ find ./ -type f -name 'file*' -exec echo {} + | wc -l
7
```

If I restrict the number of files, it fits into one:

```
$ find ./ -type f -name 'file5*' -exec echo {} + | wc -l
1
```

If you want to have a final total of the file size:

```
find ./ -type f -name 'file*' -exec du -ck {} + | awk ' $2 == "total" { T+=$1 } END { print T } '
```

note that I used `k` instead of `h` to make sure that all the results the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Apologies, what I was asking you managed to decode and answer perfectly for me! I managed to tweak my script with your input and it's now working. With my test directories I was seeing the command needed to be executed twice. Greping for 'total' made it pop out!